# Reflection or Aspect Oriented Programming to be used?

Tags: java

I have developed a web service in java which contains about 30 operations. Each operation has the exact same code except for 2-3 lines. Following is a sketch of the code

```
public Response operation1(String arg1, String arg2)
{
   initialze(); // this line will be different for each operation with different arguments
   authorizeSession();
   Response res;

   if (authorized)
   {
       try 
       {
          Object result = callMethod1(arg1, arg2); // This line is different for each operation
          res = Response.ok(result).build();
       }
       catch( MultipleExceptions ex)
       {
          res = handleExceptions();
       }
       finally
       {
           logInDatabase();
       }

   }
   return res;
}
```

What approach should i follow so that i dont have to write the same code in each operation?

1. Should i use reflection?
2. I have heard about Aspect Oriented Programming...can AOP be used here?
3. Should i go with the plain old switch case statements and a method to decide which method to call based on operation?

Comment: Do you really want to return `null` (actually the `res` variable is uninitialized) if user in unauthorized?

Comment: no...i'll be sending a not authorized response...sorry i missed that part, but thats not really related to my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like a good candidate for the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). Define an abstract class containing the main method (final), which delegates the specific parts to protected abstract methods.

In each method of your web service, instantiate a subclass of this abstract class which only overrides the two specific abstract methods, and call the main method of this subclass instance.

```
public abstract class Operation {
    public final Response answer(String arg1, String arg2) {
        authorizeSession();
        Response res;

        if (authorized) {
            try {
                Object result = executeSpecificPart(arg1, arg2);
                res = Response.ok(result).build();
            }
            catch (MultipleExceptions ex) {
                res = handleExceptions();
            }
            finally {
                logInDatabase();
            }
        }

        return res;
    }

    protected abstract Object executeSpecificPart(String arg1, String arg2);
}

...

    public Response operation1(final String arg1, final String arg2) {
        initialize();
        Operation op1 = new Operation() {
            protected Object executeSpecificPart(String arg1, String arg2) {
                ...
            }
        };
        return op1.answer();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

## Template Method pattern and/or Strategy pattern

Each method creates it's own `Callable` instance and passes it to one, general purpose `run()` method:

```
public Response operation1(String arg1, String arg2)
{
    initialze(); // this line will be different for each operation with different arguments
    return run(new Callable<Object> {
        public Object call() {
            return callMethod1(arg1, arg2); // This line is different for each operation
        }
    });
}

private Response run(Callable<Object> method) {
   authorizeSession();
   if (authorized)
   {
       try 
       {
          Object result = method.call();
          return Response.ok(result).build();
       }
       catch( MultipleExceptions ex)
       {
          return handleExceptions();
       }
       finally
       {
           logInDatabase();
       }
   }
   return null;
}
```

<s>It would have been much easier to read and write if Java had lambdas.</s>

## AOP

Aspect-oriented programming is not the best tool here since you have to intercept something *inside* the method. AOP is best suited when you need to invoke something before or after a method (or when it throws something). The same applies to reflection.

However AOP will significantly improve error handling. Your code can then be reduced to:

```
public Response operation1(String arg1, String arg2)
    {
    initialze(); // this line will be different for each operation with different arguments
    authorizeSession();

    if (authorized)
    {
        Object result = callMethod1(arg1, arg2); // This line is different for each operation
        return Response.ok(result).build();
    }
    return null;
    }
```

and catching of `MultipleExceptions` and `finally` block can be placed in `AfterThrowing` and `After` advices.

Comment: This looks more like the strategy pattern to me. But it's also a good solution. You missed the call to run() in the operation1() method. And I guess you meant "AOP is NOT the best tool".

Comment: @JBNizet: absolutely, thanks! As for the naming confusion, well `JdbcTemplate` uses this syntax - and it's called *template*. But you might be right.

Comment: so i can mix both AOP and the "strategy pattern" (another new concept for me) in this example

Comment: @orak: well, you can, but IMHO choose one of them to avoid too confusing code. In your particular case strategy seems like a better fit.

Comment: This may be a side question, but AOP libraries actually use reflection underneath, right?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can just extract the code in a private method.

1.) Reflection will make it much slower and harder to understand and maintain.

2.) AO techniques should be used when one concern crosscuts another. This is not really the case here, because `initialize` and `callMethod1` are part of the whole algorithm and cannot stand alone.

3.) The switch statement is the right way of thinking but is a sign of "polymorphismphobia".

This is how you could do it:

```
private static interface CallMethodHelper {
    Object callMethod() throws MultipleExceptions;
}

public Response operation1(final String arg1, final String arg2) {
    initialze(); 
    return operationHelper(new CallMethodHelper() {
        @Override
        public Object callMethod() throws MultipleExceptions {
            return callMethod1(arg1, arg2);
        }
    });
}

private Response operationHelper(CallMethodHelper helper) {
    authorizeSession();
    Response res = null;

    if (authorized) {
        try {
            Object result = helper.callMethod();
            res = Response.ok(result).build();
        } catch (MultipleExceptions ex) {
            res = handleExceptions();
        } finally {
            logInDatabase();
        }

    }
    return res;
}
```

Note that you have to make the arguments final, and that you can of course use generics to change the result and exception types.